# Compton effect on wavelength

Tags: wave-particle-duality

Mention the change in wave length of the photon after it collides with free electron?? 
Is the rule of particle can be applied here?

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. Do you want to know whether the photon can be seen as a particle in Compton scattering?

Comment: HI just want to know what happens to the wavelength of the photon I know that frequency decreases but I don't understant how we deal with the rules as the photon or particle

Answer (score 1):

You are probably familiar with the relation $$c = \lambda f$$ where $c$ is the speed of light, $\lambda$ the wavelength and $f$ the frequency of a photon.

The general formula for Compton scattering is normally given as $$\lambda' = \lambda_C (1-\cos \alpha) + \lambda$$ where $\lambda'$ is the wavelength of the scattered photon, $\lambda$ the initial wavelength, $\lambda_C$ the Compton wavelength $\lambda_C = \frac{h}{m_e c}$ and $\alpha$ is the angle at which the photon scatters.

From this formula, we can see that the wavelength of a photon *increases* when it scatters at an electron. To visualize, the photon gives some of its energy to the electron. The energy of a photon is given as $$E = h f$$ or $E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$ so if the wavelength increases, the energy of the photon decreases. To illustrate further, if you shoot blue light at a stationary electron, you end up with scattered red light.

For the case of electromagetic radiation (light!), you can convert between frequency and wavelength using $c = \lambda f$. Those formulas combined allow you to find the frequency and wavelength of a scattered photon.

Comment: Can I ask just an another question this means that here the photon velocity is constant which is 3×10 8

Comment: The velocity of a photon in vaccum is always c.